# GNU sort stable sort when sort does not know sort order

Tags: sort

I have a two-column file; the file is sorted the way I want it on column 1 already. I would like to sort on column 2, within each column 1 category. However, `sort` does not understand the sort order of column 1.

The normal way (from similar questions here on stack) would be this:

```
sort --stable -k1,1 -k2,2n
```

But I cannot specify the sort on k1, because it is arbitrary.

Example input:

```
C 2
C 1
A 2
A 1
B 2 
B 1
```

and output:

```
C 1
C 2
A 1
A 2
B 1 
B 2
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use awk to start a new sort for each block:

```
% awk -v cmd="sort -k2,2" '$1 != prev {close(cmd); prev=$1} {print | cmd}' foo
C 1
C 2
A 1
A 2
B 1
B 2
```

- `$1 != prev {close(cmd); prev=$1}` - when the saved value is different, we have a new block, so we close any previously started `sort`
- `{print | "sort -k2,2"}'` pipes the output to `sort`, starting it if it isn't already running (awk can keep track of commands it starts)

Comment: awk is truly incredible. I like this a lot more than what I was expecting, which was an awk decorate-sort-undecorate!

Comment: I tried to compare perf of this vs the other answer, not sure why this one uses more resources... Any ideas?
https://gist.github.com/EvanTheB/5b64eafb84eeaf51c289295ac06e1b0b

Comment: How many runs did you average across?

Comment: I did no averaging, but am seeing consistent runtimes as I repeat and investigate.

Comment: Here is a similar file to what I am using if you want to investigate: `seq 30 | xargs -L1 bash -cs 'yes $1 | head -1000000 | paste - <(seq 1000000) | shuf' bash`

Comment: @EvanBenn  Two reasons why DSR can be faster. [1] Depends on average size of group with same column 1, but awk launches a shell and a sort per group. (Here I would consider internal asort() if groups were limited size.) [2] sort with any keys evaluates each key in each compare: O (n log n). DSR is done once O(n). Even without the Col1 issue here, I measured (on Solaris) that an awk DSQ  with no key args can be tens of times faster that a sort with multiple keys.

Answer (score 12):

You could use a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) (this is basically the decorate-sort-undecorate approach you alluded to in a comment, but likely more performant than [muru's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru) [fine answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532851/21233) due to using a single `sort` invocation as opposed to multiple)  - using `awk` add a prefix column that increments with a change in value in the first column, sort by the prefix column *followed by the "second" column*(whose ordinal position has temporarily shifted to `3` due to the presence of the prefix column), and finally get rid of the prefix column

```
awk '{print ($1 in a? c+0: ++c)"\t" $0; a[$1]}' file | sort -k1,1n  -k3,3 | cut -f 2-
```

Comment: I'm surprised, but you are correct, this was faster than the other answer! 3 minutes vs 2 minutes on my 100 million line file (~30 uniq first columns).

Comment: No need to keep an array of the unique key from the first column. I think it ought to be enough to compare the current line's first column against the previous.

Comment: Something like `awk -v OFS="\t" '$1 != prev { key++ } { print key, $0; prev = $1 }` (untested).